# Embedding a Tweet

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed says that a "returned HTML snippet will be automatically recognized as an Embedded Tweet when Twitter’s widget JavaScript is included on the page."

I've included said widget on my page, and when I copy the HTML of a Tweet from a third party website it does indeed display properly as a formatted tweet. However, I don't understand how to RETURN the HTML snippet in the first place. Is the widget meant to do this? The website simply gives an example request as:

```
GET https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FInterior%2Fstatus%2F507185938620219395
```

... which isn't that helpful for someone who's never used oEmbed before. What do I do with this to return the HTML snippet??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML snippet you want is available calling the URL with a GET-request *https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=YOUR_SITE*.

Start by having a look at the different [Twitter libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries) for different programming languages to see how to connect to Twitter and get these HTML snippets.